# Learning ASP.NET MVC without any experience of WebForms, is this plausible?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Not sure how relevant this is for stackoverflow but here goes... Over a year ago friend of mine said she was interested in learning Web Development / Programming and asked me to assist in her learning. I explained some concepts, give an overview of my experience and I have taught her HTML, OO JavaScript and CSS. Now she's confident with those she said she would like to start using more powerful tools/languages and I suggested using ASP.NET with C#. I discussed my dislike of WebForms (I hated Webforms so much I jumped from using ASP/ASP.NET to PHP and ROR for a few years) however as soon as ASP.NET MVC was released I jumped back on board and I now use that as my default technology. I suggested that she disregards Webforms and just learns MVC using C#, when giving her resources (Books, Videos, etc) I noticed that most of these assume that the developer is familiar with WebForms or the resources devote 90% of their content to Webforms and 10% to MVC!

I'm now unsure if I've given the correct advise and perhaps made her learning harder due to most resources focus on or assume knowledge of Webforms. Has anyone got an opinion or experience of learning MVC with or without WebForms knowledge. If you were successful in learning ASP.NET MVC without Webforms knowledge please give advice on how you achieved this (resources, books, sites, etc).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try searching before asking. There was a lot of questions about MVC / WebForms relations.

Comment: Point noted. Won't happen again...

Comment: My MVC tutorials don't assume any Web Forms. See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc-4-and-visual-studio-2011/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous exposure to WebForms can even be a hindrance to effectively learning and using MVC. Most online tutorials and books I read on the subject didn't assume any WebForms experience whatsoever.

Here's a book I can recommend: [ASP.NET MVC 4 in Action](http://manning.com/palermo3/)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you already know.

Learning MVC from WebForms requires that you un-learn the horrible abstraction that is WebForms.

WebForms was built so MS could easily port all its loyal winforms devs to the web, instead of helping them learn any kind of sensible paradigm or practices.

The best thing to learn first is HTTP, and how requests are actually made on the web. If you understand this, youre set for any half decent framework, its just learning he syntax